# Angular Template-drivaen Validation not working

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and trying out template-driven validation which is not working, I am trying to add a message if the FirstName field in empty using bootstrap and unable to see the message when *ngIf is applied.Please help, thanks in advance.
 Below is my code:

```
       <form>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="firstName">
          Frist name
        </label>
        <input ngModel name="firstName" id="firstName" #firstName="ngModel" 
             (change)="log(firstName)" type="text" class="form-control">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="firstName.touched && 
              !firstName.valid">first name mandatory</div>

         </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="comment">
               Comment
              </label>
       <textarea ngModel name="comment" id='comment' cols="30" rows="10" 
          class="form-control">
      </textarea>
         </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Well, you just forgot to add the validation constraint: `<input ... required>`. So it's always valid. So your message never appears.

Comment: Thanks a lot..it worked!!